Persistent Flutter Bottom Navigation with android back-button
What I am trying to do is to implement a bottom navigation bar in my flutter app using go router. After reading couple of articles I came to know that to implement a persistent bottom navigation I have to use  StatefulShellRoute of go router. So I have implemented the StatefulShellRoute. But I am not getting my expected output using this code.
This Is My Router Class
class AppNavigation {
  AppNavigation._();

  static final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _homeTabNavigatorKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _settingsTabNavigatorKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _profileTabNavigatorKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  static final router = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
    initialLocation: "/home",
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: SplashScreen.routePath,
        name: SplashScreen.routeName,
        pageBuilder: (context, state) => getPage(
          child: const SplashScreen(),
          state: state,
        ),
      ),
      StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
        parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
        pageBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          GoRouterState state,
          StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell,
        ) {
          return getPage(
            child: BottomNavigationScreen(
              child: navigationShell,
            ),
            state: state,
          );
        },
        branches: [
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _homeTabNavigatorKey,
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: "/home",
                pageBuilder: (context, GoRouterState state) {
                  return getPage(
                    child: const HomeScreen(),
                    state: state,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _settingsTabNavigatorKey,
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: "/settings",
                pageBuilder: (context, GoRouterState state) {
                  return getPage(
                    child: const SettingsScreen(),
                    state: state,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _profileTabNavigatorKey,
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: "/profile",
                pageBuilder: (context, GoRouterState state) {
                  return getPage(
                    child: const ProfileScreen(),
                    state: state,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  );

  static Page getPage({
    required Widget child,
    required GoRouterState state,
  }) {
    return MaterialPage(
      key: state.pageKey,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

This is My Bottom Navigation Screen
class BottomNavigationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigationScreen({super.key, required this.child});
  final StatefulNavigationShell child;
  @override
  State<BottomNavigationScreen> createState() => _BottomNavigationScreenState();
}

class _BottomNavigationScreenState extends State<BottomNavigationScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bottom Navigator Shell'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: widget.child,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: widget.child.currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          widget.child.goBranch(
            index,
            initialLocation: index == widget.child.currentIndex,
          );

          setState(() {});
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Settings',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Expected Output:

Output:

What I am not getting is when I am using my device back button it is closing the app. But what I want to achieve is, when I will use my device back button it go back to previous tab.

Have you tried implementing the PopScope with your custom implementation? It will work with this scenario.

Can you explain?  I have tried it but it is not giving me expected output!

You can wrap your widget with this code. PopScope(
canPop: widget.child.currentIndex == 0,
onPopInvoked: (bool) {
}, and in onpopInvoked you can add the logic for navigation of previous screens. by implementing this your app will be only closed when the currentIndex is 0. Try and le me know if it works.

This the issue i am facing..  How can i keep track? Of the screens?

When i pop screen!  I doesn't change the bottom navigation bar's active icon. It only changes the screen!

Can you share your code so I can check and try to solve it?

Yes!  Should I share the git hub repo link with you?

It would be helpful but first give it a try by yourself if not working can share.

I found that if I change class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() instead of class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {}
The navigation works PERFECT. The problem is that I need my app to use FlutterFragmentActivity since I'm using STRIPE.
This is a solution that is working for me for now is to create custom onNavigationNotification in MaterialApp.router constructor.
bool _defaultOnNavigationNotification(NavigationNotification _) {
  switch (WidgetsBinding.instance.lifecycleState) {
    case null:
    case AppLifecycleState.detached:
    case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
    // Avoid updating the engine when the app isn't ready.
      return true;
    case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
    case AppLifecycleState.hidden:
    case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      SystemNavigator.setFrameworkHandlesBack(true); /// This must be `true` instead of `notification.canHandlePop`, otherwise application closes on back gesture.
      return true;
  }
}

And then:
MaterialApp.router(
  onNavigationNotification: _defaultOnNavigationNotification,
);

Reference link
